# Custom UITableViewCell and subviews position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subviews, layoutsubviews

In my custom UITableViewCell i rewrite method (void) layoutSubviews, in this method i set new subviews position:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < views.count; ++i) {
    ViewData *viewData = (ViewData *)[views objectAtIndex:i];

    CGFloat x_pos = i <= currentViewPos ? 0 : contentViewWidth;
    viewData.x_current = x_pos + viewData.width * viewData.x_anchor;

    [viewData.view setCenter:CGPointMake(viewData.x_current, viewData.view.center.y)];

    if (i < currentViewPos) {
        [viewData.view setAlpha:0.5f];
    } else {
        [viewData.view setAlpha:1.0f];
    }
}
```

When my Table loaded at first time - all items have correct positions, but when i press on some item, and push next view controller, and then go back to my Table - second and next subviews don't visible on screen. Only Alpha property will be correct. But layoutSubviews is called.
If i try to scroll my UITableView - items which was redrawn will be shown correctly.

What am I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you NSLog to see whether the values you're giving for CGPointMake make sense?

Comment: Yes, I sure hope ViewData is not a UIViewController, because if it is, this is all totally illegal.

Comment: I use NSLog(@"x: %f", viewData.view.center.x);, and it shown me correct X coordinate. But at display i don't see changes.

Comment: ViewData - its my custom interface, contains data for animation subviews...

Comment: Do you have xib for your customTableView ??